# Serialization of non-primitives using Jackson

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I am trying to serialize a JSON object using Jackson and save into a mysql database using hibernate. All fields of my POJO class are able to be serialized except for any field that isn't a primitive.

```
public class Teacher {

    private Set<Student> students;
    private int id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In this case it would fail on students, creating an infinite recursive loop through the reference chain. I can stop it with `@JsonIgnoreProperty` but I want this field to be serialized. I am serializing my object like so:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Teacher myTeacher = new Teacher();
mapper.writeValueAsString(teacher);
```

The only workaround I can think of is appending a string to the end of teacher while still ignoring the property but I am not sure if I will be able to read students as a JsonNode from the tree if I do this.

Comment: You can use back references.

Answer (score 0):

A way around this would be to use a pure Array or an ArrayList which are serialized fine with Jackson.

For example, I can serialize a class with all these parameters :

```java
public class Map{

    private short [][] someMapType;
    private short [][] someOtherMap;

    private ArrayList<Mill> someMills, otherMills;
    private ArrayList<OtherPOJO> myPOJOList;
    private String action = "myDefaultAction";

    ...
}
```

Where Mill and OtherPOJO are class with not much more than a couple of arrays and other primitives : pure POJOs.

It works fine both ways with Jackson and MongoJack (jackson serializer for MongoDb).

If you can't get away from the set than you have to understand properly what is the fundamental data structure in a set. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) should help but you are probably already aware of that.

A way to work around this structure limitation would be to create non-dumb getters and setters. The main disadvantage behind this method is that you run one more for loop over all your elements every time you serialize or de-serialize. This might slightly reduce performance.

The getter is fairly simple :

```
public Student[] getStudents(){
    return this.students.toArray();
}
```

And the setter is also pretty trivial :

```
public void setStudents(Student[] students){

    this.students = new Set<Student>(); // Or anything that builds the right Set for you
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        this.students.add(students[i]);
    }
}
```

I wrote it quickly, let me know if there is any bug.

I hope it helps!

Comment: giving me the same issue using the 2nd method :(

Comment: Could you add the code of your Student class? I will try it on my end. Did you try it with the latest jackson?

Answer (score 0):

Found a decent workaround:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

@JsonProperty("Students")
public String getStudentsForJson() {
    String[] studentNames = new String[this.students.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(Student student : this.students) {
        studentNames[i] = student.getName();
        i++;
    }
    return StringUtils.join(studentNames, ", ");
}
```

This saves all student names as one string which I'm able to easily serialize and deserialize as a field.